# Is there any resource to connect compute resource on AWS RDS using terraform

Tags: terraform, amazon-rds, terraform-provider-aws

I've created EC2, RDS within VPC and wanted to connect compute resource to it.
Searched for the same however couldn't find it.
Is there any resource or parameter to connect it on terraform.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The RDS "connection" to compute resources is really just an automatic way for RDS to [open its security group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/ec2-rds-connect.html) rules to specific compute resources for you. This RDS feature was added as a way for people that don't really understand how AWS networking works to have RDS do the work for them.

As the text on your screenshot shows, the screen you are on will only show security group rules that RDS has created automatically. It won't show any that you created manually. And as far as RDS knows, any security group rules you create with Terraform were manually created.

So no, you can't do anything in Terraform to get your security group rules to show up on that specific screen, but that screen is completely pointless for anyone using Terraform anyway. Just create [the security group rules](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/-/aws/latest/docs/resources/security_group_rule) you need via Terraform.